# swift 6 random numbers to 6 images in a tableViewCell

Tags: swift

I am pretty new to Swift and I cant find the answer to my issue with Swift.

Creating an lotto number generator and I can do it using a label but I'm having difficulties mapping these numbers to images (e.g. lotto ball images) so whenever numbers are populated, it will convert these numbers to images and shows in a custom Cell.

Currently using a `tableView` with customer Cell - i have six `UIImageView` in a cell.

Through out my practice, i found myself repeating the same codes. e.g. `ball1.image = arc4Random_uniform(45)` and ball2 ball3 and so on.. want to learn the harder way. i mean not repeating the codes. please masters how could i populate 6 numbers from 1-45 without duplicate and shows 6 lotto ball images in a cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce code usage, make methods on the view controller and call it with the array of image views.
Here is the method:

```
func setImages(imageViews: [UIImageView]) {
      var numSet = Set<Int>()
      while numSet.count < imageViews.count
      {
          numSet.insert(Int(arc4random_uniform(45)) + 1) // Assuming you want numbers from 1 to 45 inclusive of both.
      }
      for (i, elem) in numSet.sort(<).enumerate() // Don't use sort if not needed.
      {
            imageViews[i].image = UIImage(named: "lotto\(elem).png") // Or whatever naming convention you used for the images.
      }
}
```

Just call the setImages with the array of imageViews. It uses the count of the array to generate enough numbers. Don't forget to change the naming scheme used for the images. I assumed you used a naming scheme of lotto1.png, lotto2.png ... lotto44.png

Comment: its kind what i wanted but there is no function i can use numSet.sort in xcode and can you please help me again to do it for another 6 UIImageview?

Comment: `Set`s have a sort method in Swift 2. In any case if you are using an older version of swift you can convert it to an array and call sort on the array. So like this `enumerate(Array<Int>(numSet).sort(<))`

Comment: And to do it for another 6 UIImageViews just call this method again with the other 6 image views.

Comment: Thanks Manav, I learned alot from your example :) but something i cannot figure out. having difficulties understanding (imageViews: [UIImageView]) part. i know you used it later in the method but why? im a newbie but huge desire learning! Thanks !

Comment: I added the `imageViews: [UIImageView]` says that the function takes an array of UIImageViews which are used to display the lotto numbers that you want to display. So you can call this function as many times as you like with the image views array to fill in the images. So let's say you have 3 image views and you want to show the 3 lotto numbers on those image views you would call the function like this: `setImages([imageView1, imageView2, imageView3])`. Now the `imageViewX`s can be IBOutlets that you set up inside IB and then the images get set for you by the function.

Comment: Manav, i think i understood but and the 6imageviews part. i got a problem it generates the same number. how can i avoid having same numbers appear?  Thanks! A LOT!

Comment: If you use my solution there will be no duplicates since we are using a Set of integers. Do you mean the numbers are repeated between different calls to the function?

Comment: this is how i understood            self.lottoBallImage1.image = UIImage(named:"\(elem).png")
            self.lottoBallImage2.image = UIImage(named:"\(elem).png")
            self.lottoBallImage3.image = UIImage(named:"\(elem).png")
            self.lottoBallImage4.image = UIImage(named:"\(elem).png")
            self.lottoBallImage5.image = UIImage(named:"\(elem).png")
            self.lottoBallImage6.image = UIImage(named:"\(elem).png")

Comment: all 6 imagesviews have the same number whenever generated

Comment: You are missing a backslash to interpolate the number into the string it should be UIImage(named: "\(elem).png"). Also you don't need to do this manually, just call the function like this: `setImages([lottoBallImage1, lottoBallImage2, lottoBallImage3, etc. ])`

Comment: the Backslash was removed by Stackoverflow. in method i tried what you said. lottoBallImage1.image = UIImage(named:"\(elem).png") and when call method setImages([lottoBallImage1, lottoBallImage2, lottoBallImage3, lottoBallImage4, lottoBallImage5, lottoBallImage6]) and i'm seeing just 1 image.

Comment: Oh yeah it happened to my comment too, that's weird. Anyway, I just realized that I my code was slightly wrong in that I was assigning the image to `imageView` instead of `imageViews[i]`. My bad. Also to check the numbers are different just put a print statement like: `print(elem)` and you will see that all the numbers are different so there must be a problem in how you are assigning the images?

Comment: THANKS!!! THIS WORKS NOW!!!! Wow.. I gotta say, people like you making us newbies learn a lot better. Thanks man! just another question not relating this. How long should i study or experience more to get to your level of swift? I rally want to learn.. but its just taking so much time now.

Comment: It all depends on how much programming experience you've had before this. If you know object oriented programming, you will pick up Swift really quickly but if you don't it may take some time to wrap your head around concepts. Its always difficult to learn something new just make sure you don't give up and you'll be fine eventually, you will reach a point where learning new concepts is not so difficult and you will be really glad. Also, as a side note I really love swift because its an amazing language and I'm sure you will learn it quickly.